# How to list and numbered array values using awk with unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

Can be possible to format an output values from an array like a list and numbered using "awk"?

I did get the way to just print the list but want number without using a loop, that could be possible?

This is what I have to list the values of the array:

```
set -A MyArray $(ls)

printf "%s\n" ${MyArray [@]}
```

OUTPUT:

```
File1.txt
File2.txt
File3.txt
```

I want to do something like:

```
1- File1.txt
2- File.txt
3- File3.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want array specifically then this could be done this way

```
printf "%s\n" ${MyArray [@]} | awk '{i++; print i"-", $0}'
```

or

```
awk '{print ++i"-", $0}' <<<"${MyArray[@]}"
```

Comment: I edited your answer, I tried the same way you did it but and I did it with the array and it worked like a charm! thank you @batMan!